# Write RTP payload data to an audio file using FFmpeg API

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encoder

My task is to write the payload data of an `RTP` packet to an audio file. To do this, in the example below, I implemented an audio encoder that takes a small amount of audio data (such as `pcm_alaw`, `pcm_mulaw`, `pcm_s16le`, `pcm_s16be`, and so on) and saves it to an audio file. But there is a problem when trying to record formats such as `opus`, `flac`, `gsm`, and so on. The **av_find_input_format** function cannot find formats such as opus. And I thought, is it possible to just send the received audio data of the `RTP` packet to muxer ?

As mentioned above, I attach the code (only works with `pcm_alaw`, `pcm_mulaw`, `pcm_s16le`, `pcm_s16be`, `pcm_s32le`, `pcm_s32be`):

```cpp
// For QT pro file
// INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/ffmpeg
// QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
// LIBS += -L/usr/local/lib -lz
// LIBS += -lm -lpthread -lavcodec -lavdevice -lavfilter -lavformat -lavresample -lavutil -lpostproc -lswresample -lswscale

#include <QDebug>
#include <QFile>

extern "C" {

#include <libavutil/log.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/frame.h>
#include <libavformat/avio.h>
#include <libavutil/avassert.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavutil/avstring.h>
#include <libavfilter/avfilter.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/audio_fifo.h>
#include <libswresample/swresample.h>
}

class AudioEncoderSettings {
public:
    static const QString DEF_OUTPUT_FILE;
    static const quint16 DEF_CHANNELS;
    static const quint32 DEF_SAMPLE_RATE;
    static const quint32 DEF_BIT_RATE;
    static const QString DEF_AUDIO_CODEC;

public:
    AudioEncoderSettings(void) = default;
    AudioEncoderSettings& operator=(const AudioEncoderSettings& other) = default;
    AudioEncoderSettings& operator=(AudioEncoderSettings&& other) = default;
    AudioEncoderSettings(const AudioEncoderSettings& other) = default;
    AudioEncoderSettings(AudioEncoderSettings&& other) = default;
    ~AudioEncoderSettings(void) = default;

    bool operator==(const AudioEncoderSettings& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const AudioEncoderSettings& other) const;

    quint32 sampleRate(void) const noexcept;
    quint16 channelCount(void) const noexcept;
    QString audioCodec(void) const noexcept;
    quint32 constBitRate(void) const noexcept;
    QString outputFile(void) const noexcept;

    void setSampleRate(const quint32& val) noexcept;
    void setChannelCount(const quint16& val) noexcept;
    void setAudioCodec(const QString& val) noexcept;
    void setConstBitRate(const quint32& val) noexcept;
    void setOutputFile(const QString& val) noexcept;

private:
    quint32 m_sampleRate{ DEF_SAMPLE_RATE };
    quint16 m_channelCount{ DEF_CHANNELS };
    QString m_audioCodec{ DEF_AUDIO_CODEC };
    quint32 m_constBitRate{ DEF_BIT_RATE };
    QString m_outputFile{ DEF_AUDIO_CODEC };
};

using Settings = AudioEncoderSettings;

const quint32 AudioEncoderSettings::DEF_SAMPLE_RATE = 0x1f40;
const quint16 AudioEncoderSettings::DEF_CHANNELS = 0x0001;
const QString AudioEncoderSettings::DEF_OUTPUT_FILE = QString();
const quint32 AudioEncoderSettings::DEF_BIT_RATE = 0xfa00;
const QString AudioEncoderSettings::DEF_AUDIO_CODEC = "alaw";

quint32 AudioEncoderSettings::sampleRate(void) const noexcept
{
    return m_sampleRate;
}

quint16 AudioEncoderSettings::channelCount(void) const noexcept
{
    return m_channelCount;
}

QString AudioEncoderSettings::audioCodec(void) const noexcept
{
    return m_audioCodec;
}

quint32 AudioEncoderSettings::constBitRate(void) const noexcept
{
    return m_constBitRate;
}

QString AudioEncoderSettings::outputFile(void) const noexcept
{
    return m_outputFile;
}

void AudioEncoderSettings::setSampleRate(const quint32& val) noexcept
{
    m_sampleRate = val;
}

void AudioEncoderSettings::setChannelCount(const quint16& val) noexcept
{
    m_channelCount = val;
}

void AudioEncoderSettings::setAudioCodec(const QString& val) noexcept
{
    m_audioCodec = val;
}

void AudioEncoderSettings::setConstBitRate(const quint32& val) noexcept
{
    m_constBitRate = val;
}

void AudioEncoderSettings::setOutputFile(const QString& val) noexcept
{
    m_outputFile = val;
}

bool AudioEncoderSettings::operator==(const AudioEncoderSettings& other) const
{
    return (m_sampleRate == other.m_sampleRate && m_channelCount == other.m_channelCount && m_audioCodec == other.m_audioCodec && m_constBitRate == other.m_constBitRate && m_outputFile == other.m_outputFile);
}

bool AudioEncoderSettings::operator!=(const AudioEncoderSettings& other) const
{
    return (m_sampleRate != other.m_sampleRate && m_channelCount != other.m_channelCount && m_audioCodec != other.m_audioCodec && m_constBitRate != other.m_constBitRate && m_outputFile != other.m_outputFile);
}

using AudioStr = AVStream;
using AudioCtx = AVIOContext;
using AudioDic = AVDictionary;
using AudioCdc = AVCodecContext;
using AudioFrm = AVFormatContext;

class AudioEncoder {
public:
    AudioEncoder(const Settings& settings);
    AudioEncoder& operator=(const AudioEncoder& rhs) = delete;
    AudioEncoder& operator=(AudioEncoder&& rhs) = delete;
    AudioEncoder(const AudioEncoder& rhs) = delete;
    AudioEncoder(AudioEncoder&& rhs) = delete;
    ~AudioEncoder(void) = default;

    bool init(void) noexcept;
    bool record(const QByteArray& rawData) noexcept;
    bool term(void) noexcept;

private:
    QString getMessageByErrorCode(const qint32& code) noexcept;
    bool proc(void) noexcept;

private:
    class Deleter {
    public:
        static void cleanup(AudioFrm* p);
        static void cleanup(AudioCdc* p);
        static void cleanup(AudioCtx* p);
        static void cleanup(AudioStr* p);
        static void cleanup(Settings* p);
        static void cleanup(AudioDic* p);
    };

    QScopedPointer<Settings, Deleter> p_sets{ nullptr };
    QScopedPointer<AudioStr, Deleter> p_iStr{ nullptr };
    QScopedPointer<AudioStr, Deleter> p_oStr{ nullptr };
    QScopedPointer<AudioCtx, Deleter> p_inIOCtx{ nullptr };
    QScopedPointer<AudioFrm, Deleter> p_iFrmCtx{ nullptr };
    QScopedPointer<AudioFrm, Deleter> p_oFrmCtx{ nullptr };

public:
    qsizetype m_curSize{};
    const uint8_t* p_curData{};
};

QString AudioEncoder::getMessageByErrorCode(const qint32& code) noexcept
{
    if (code != 0) {
        char errorBuffer[255]{ '0' };
        av_strerror(code, errorBuffer, sizeof(errorBuffer));
        return QString(errorBuffer);
    }
    return QString();
}

qint32 readPacket(void* opaque, quint8* buf, qint32 sz)
{
    AudioEncoder* self = static_cast<AudioEncoder*>(opaque);
    if (self->p_curData && self->m_curSize) {
        sz = std::min(sz, (int)self->m_curSize);
        memcpy(buf, self->p_curData, sz);
        self->m_curSize -= sz;
        self->p_curData += sz;
        return sz;
    }
    else {
        return AVERROR(EAGAIN);
    }
}

AudioEncoder::AudioEncoder(const Settings& settings)
    : p_sets(nullptr)
    , p_iStr(nullptr)
    , p_oStr(nullptr)
    , p_inIOCtx(nullptr)
    , p_iFrmCtx(nullptr)
    , p_oFrmCtx(nullptr)
{
    p_sets.reset(new Settings(settings));
}

void AudioEncoder::Deleter::cleanup(AudioFrm* p)
{
    if (p != nullptr)
        avformat_close_input(&p);
}

void AudioEncoder::Deleter::cleanup(AudioCdc* p)
{
    if (p != nullptr)
        avcodec_free_context(&p);
}

void AudioEncoder::Deleter::cleanup(AudioCtx* p)
{
    if (p != nullptr)
        av_freep(&p->buffer);
    avio_context_free(&p);
}

void AudioEncoder::Deleter::cleanup(AudioStr* p)
{
    if (p != nullptr)
        p = nullptr;
}

void AudioEncoder::Deleter::cleanup(Settings* p)
{
    if (p != nullptr)
        delete p;
}

void AudioEncoder::Deleter::cleanup(AudioDic* p)
{
    if (p != nullptr)
        av_dict_free(&p);
}

bool AudioEncoder::init(void) noexcept
{
    if (p_oFrmCtx) {
        return true;
    }
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();

    AVInputFormat* file_iformat = av_find_input_format(p_sets->audioCodec().toStdString().c_str());
    if (file_iformat == nullptr) {
        qDebug() << QString("Unknown input format: '%1'").arg(p_sets->audioCodec());
        return false;
    }

    AudioDic* format_opts = nullptr;
    const qint32 sampleRateErrorCode = av_dict_set(&format_opts, "sample_rate",
        QString::number(p_sets->sampleRate()).toStdString().c_str(), 0);
    const qint32 bitRateErrorCode = av_dict_set(&format_opts, "bit_rate",
        QString::number(p_sets->constBitRate()).toStdString().c_str(), 0);
    qint32 channelErrorCode = 0;

    // because we set audio_channels based on both the "ac" and
    // "channel_layout" options, we need to check that the specified
    // demuxer actually has the "channels" option before setting it
    if (file_iformat && file_iformat->priv_class && av_opt_find(&file_iformat->priv_class, "channels", NULL, 0, AV_OPT_SEARCH_FAKE_OBJ)) {
        channelErrorCode = av_dict_set(&format_opts, "channels",
            QString::number(p_sets->channelCount()).toStdString().c_str(), 0);
    }

    if ((bitRateErrorCode < 0) || (sampleRateErrorCode < 0) || (channelErrorCode < 0)) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        return false;
    }

    AVFormatContext* ic;
    /* get default parameters from command line */
    ic = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (!ic) {
        qDebug() << "Error: " << __LINE__;
        return false;
    }

    const qint32 iBufSize = 4096;
    quint8* iCtxBuffer = static_cast<quint8*>(av_malloc(iBufSize));
    if (!iCtxBuffer) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        return false;
    }

    p_inIOCtx.reset(avio_alloc_context(
        iCtxBuffer, iBufSize, 0, this, &readPacket, nullptr, nullptr));
    if (!p_inIOCtx) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        return false;
    }

    ic->pb = p_inIOCtx.get();
    int errorCode = 0;
    if ((errorCode = avformat_open_input(&ic,
             p_sets->outputFile().toStdString().c_str(), file_iformat, &format_opts))
        < 0) {
        ic = nullptr;
        qDebug() << QString("Could not open output file: %1 (error: %2)").arg(p_sets->outputFile()).arg(getMessageByErrorCode(errorCode));
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        return false;
    }
    p_iFrmCtx.reset(ic);
    if (p_iFrmCtx->nb_streams != 1) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        return false;
    }

    p_iStr.reset(p_iFrmCtx->streams[0]);
    AVCodec* iCdc = avcodec_find_decoder(p_iStr->codecpar->codec_id);
    if (!iCdc) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        return false;
    }
    qDebug() << "Decoder found: " << iCdc->name;

    AudioCdc* iCdcCtx = avcodec_alloc_context3(iCdc);
    if (!iCdcCtx) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        return false;
    }

    avcodec_parameters_to_context(iCdcCtx, p_iStr->codecpar);
    if (avcodec_open2(iCdcCtx, iCdc, &format_opts) < 0) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        return false;
    }

    int ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(p_iStr->codecpar, iCdcCtx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        qDebug() << "Error initializing the decoder context";
        return false;
    }

    // Open output file ........
    AVDictionary* opts = nullptr;
    av_dict_copy(&opts, format_opts, 0);

    AudioFrm* f = nullptr;
    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(
            &f,
            nullptr,
            nullptr,
            p_sets->outputFile().toStdString().c_str())
        < 0) {

        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        avcodec_free_context(&iCdcCtx);
        return false;
    }

    p_oFrmCtx.reset(f);
    if (!(p_oFrmCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&p_oFrmCtx->pb,
                p_sets->outputFile().toStdString().c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)
            < 0) {
            if (format_opts != nullptr)
                av_dict_free(&format_opts);
            av_free(iCtxBuffer);
            avcodec_free_context(&iCdcCtx);
            return false;
        }
    }

    p_oStr.reset(avformat_new_stream(p_oFrmCtx.get(), NULL));
    if (!p_oStr) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        avcodec_free_context(&iCdcCtx);
        return false;
    }

    if (avcodec_parameters_copy(p_oStr->codecpar, p_iStr->codecpar) < 0) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);
        avcodec_free_context(&iCdcCtx);
        return false;
    }

    p_oStr->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
    av_dict_free(&format_opts);
    if (avformat_write_header(p_oFrmCtx.get(), 0) < 0) {
        if (format_opts != nullptr)
            av_dict_free(&format_opts);
        av_free(iCtxBuffer);

        avcodec_free_context(&iCdcCtx);
        return false;
    }
    avcodec_free_context(&iCdcCtx);
    return true;
}

bool AudioEncoder::proc(void) noexcept
{
    AVPacket pkt{};
    while (true) {
        const qint32 rc = av_read_frame(p_iFrmCtx.get(), &pkt);
        if (rc < 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (rc == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || rc == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        }
        if (pkt.stream_index == p_iStr->index) {

            pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, p_iStr->time_base, p_oStr->time_base,
                static_cast<enum AVRounding>(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, p_iStr->time_base, p_oStr->time_base,
                static_cast<enum AVRounding>(AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));

            pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, p_iStr->time_base, p_oStr->time_base);
            pkt.pos = -1;
            if (av_interleaved_write_frame(
                    p_oFrmCtx.get(), &pkt)
                < 0) {
                av_packet_unref(&pkt);
                return false;
            }
            av_packet_unref(&pkt);
        }
    }
    return m_curSize == 0;
}

bool AudioEncoder::record(const QByteArray& rawData) noexcept
{
    if (p_oFrmCtx) {
        if (!rawData.isEmpty()) {
            if (p_inIOCtx->error == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
                p_inIOCtx->eof_reached = 0;
            }
            p_curData = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(rawData.data());
            m_curSize = rawData.size();
            return proc();
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool AudioEncoder::term(void) noexcept
{
    if (p_oFrmCtx) {
        proc();
        qint32 error = 0;
        if ((error = av_write_trailer(p_oFrmCtx.get())) < 0) {
            qDebug() << QString("Could not write output file "
                                "trailer (error '%1')")
                            .arg(getMessageByErrorCode(error));
            return false;
        }
        p_iStr.reset();
        p_oStr.reset();
        p_inIOCtx.reset();
        p_iFrmCtx.reset();
        p_oFrmCtx.reset();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    AudioEncoderSettings settings;
    settings.setAudioCodec("alaw");
    settings.setOutputFile("/home/test/result.mka");
    settings.setSampleRate(8000);
    settings.setChannelCount(1);
    settings.setConstBitRate(64000);

    AudioEncoder encoder(settings);
    if (encoder.init()) {
        QFile file("/home/test/rawAlawRtpPayloadData.bin");
        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
        QByteArray arr(file.readAll());
        if (encoder.record(arr)) {
            return encoder.term();
        }
    }
    return encoder.term();
}
```

Comment: Not a solution to your problem, but have you ever tried to iterate over all available codes and their names? My guess is that libav has been compiled without opus support.

Answer (score 0):

try to open the socket via ffmpeg using sdp file, it will open the socket and get the av_find_input_format from your sdp file.

then it will read the packets direct from the socket so you can decode/encode it.

it is much easier !

Comment: I agree with you, but unfortunately, I get packages in binary form (I get each package as a `QByteArray`)